# How to change Stripe icon position?

Tags: stripe-payments

What I have:

[image]

What I want to do:

[image]

I'm using this options:

```
this.stripeElements.cardNumber = this.$stripe.elements.create('cardNumber', {
  showIcon: true,
  iconStyle: 'solid',
  style: {
    base: {
      fontFamily: '\'DM Sans\', sans-serif',
      fontSize: '14px',
      color: '#666573',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#9E9CAD',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
      },
    }
  }
});
```

`iconPosition: 'right'` is not working. Is there any options to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with the icon inside the field, but you can do it separately.  You can find an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/L96q8uj5/) which goes something like this (but see the JSFiddle for all the details):

```
var cardBrandToPfClass = {
    'visa': 'pf-visa',
  'mastercard': 'pf-mastercard',
  'amex': 'pf-american-express',
  'discover': 'pf-discover',
  'diners': 'pf-diners',
  'jcb': 'pf-jcb',
  'unknown': 'pf-credit-card',
}

function setBrandIcon(brand) {
    var brandIconElement = document.getElementById('brand-icon');
  var pfClass = 'pf-credit-card';
  if (brand in cardBrandToPfClass) {
    pfClass = cardBrandToPfClass[brand];
  }
  for (var i = brandIconElement.classList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    brandIconElement.classList.remove(brandIconElement.classList[i]);
  }
  brandIconElement.classList.add('pf');
  brandIconElement.classList.add(pfClass);
}

cardNumberElement.on('change', function(event) {
    // Switch brand logo
    if (event.brand) {
    setBrandIcon(event.brand);
  }

    setOutcome(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Effective and less code for stripe icon position :

```
cardNumberElement.on('change', function(event) {
    // Switch brand logo
    if (event.brand) {
        $('.brand-icon span').removeAttr("class");
        $(".brand-icon span").addClass(event.brand);
    }else{
          // default class
        $('.brand-icon span').removeAttr("class");
        $(".brand-icon span").addClass('credit-card');          
    }

});
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="card-title"> Payment Details 
   <span class="discover"></span> 
</div>
```

You can manage the icon by following under given CSS code :

```
.card-title span.visa {
    background-image: url(VISA_CARD_ICON);
}
.card-title span.discover {
    background-image: url(DISCOVER_CARD_ICON);
}
.card-title span.master {
    background-image: url(MASTER_CARD_ICON);
}
```

Final Output ScreenShot :

[image]